# How do I get the exit point from a QDragLeaveEvent?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

**Note:** I'm working with PyQt5.

### 1. The problem

I'm experimenting for the first time with "dragging" QWidgets in my application. I found out how to obtain the drag entry point, by overriding the `dragEnterEvent` in the relevant widget:

```
    # Override
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()
            print("Drag entered at: " + str(event.pos()))
```

Unfortunately, the same cannot be done for a `dragLeaveEvent`. I get the following error when trying:

> AttributeError: `QDragLeaveEvent` object has no attribute 'pos'

### 2. Demo app

I've built a tiny standalone demonstration application that spawns a `QMainWindow` with a `QLineEdit`-widget inside. For that widget, I've overridden all the relevant functions to enable dragging (`mousePressEvent(..)`, `mouseMoveEvent(..)`, `dragEnterEvent(..)`, ...).
Please copy-paste the code below to see the demo:

[image]

Demo code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


'''================================================================================'''
'''|                           CUSTOM QLINE-EDIT                                  |'''
'''================================================================================'''
class CustomLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLineEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.dragStartPosition = 0
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.setFixedWidth(300)

    ''''''

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(CustomLineEdit, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if (event.button() == Qt.RightButton) or (event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier):
            return
        else:
            self.dragStartPosition = event.pos()
        ###

    ''''''

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        if event.buttons() == Qt.NoButton:
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        # Start dragging
        # ---------------
        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setPixmap(QPixmap("cmd.png"))
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText("my mime data")
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        dropAction = drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)

    ''''''

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()
            print("Drag entered at: " + str(event.pos()))
        ###

    ''''''

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        # print("Drag left at: " + str(event.pos()))  # <- doesn't work :-(
        print("Drag left at: ?")

    ''''''

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("text/plain"):
            event.acceptProposedAction()
            print("Drag dropped at: " + str(event.pos()))
        ###

    ''''''


'''================================================================================'''
'''|                           CUSTOM MAIN WINDOW                                 |'''
'''================================================================================'''
class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # -------------------------------- #
        #           Window setup           #
        # -------------------------------- #

        # 1. Define the geometry of the main window
        # ------------------------------------------
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QLineEdit test")

        # 2. Create frame and layout
        # ---------------------------
        self.__frm = QFrame(self)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #ffffff }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)

        # 3. Create QLineEdit
        # -------------------
        self.__myQLineEdit = CustomLineEdit()
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myQLineEdit)


        self.show()

'''=== end Class ==='''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

''''''
```

### 3. Output of the Demo app

Please run the demo code. When the window appears, click somewhere in the QLineEdit-widget and move your mouse in and out. You should get some output like this in your console/terminal:

```
Drag entered at: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(100, 22)
Drag left at: ?
Drag entered at: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(132, 49)
Drag left at: ?
Drag entered at: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(229, 49)
Drag left at: ?
Drag entered at: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(242, 49)
Drag dropped at: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(230, 23)
```

As you can see, I have no easy way to detect the exit points.

Please help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the position is to use `QCursor::pos()` that returns the global position, and convert it to a position relative to the widget using `mapFromGlobal()`:

```
def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
    event.accept()
    print("Drag left at: " + str(self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())))
```

Comment: Magical! This works like a charm. Awesome! Thank you :-D

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I've donated $5 to show my appreciation ;-)

Comment: @K.Mulier hahaha, today I'll have my coffee. :-D

Comment: Enjoy it. A coder like you deserves the best coffee ;-)

Comment: any chance to get the Qwidget name , reference, object being dragged around like the source in def eventFilter(self, source, event): ???