# PyQt get sender/source of DragLeaveEvent

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

hi got this bit of code in **PyQt5** (PyQt: v 5.15.7) , basically I am trying to track widget that are dragged outside QMainwindow :

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, 
                             
                             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QGridLayout
                             )
                            
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QCursor

class DragWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, name , **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    
    whereDropped = pyqtSignal(int,int)
    
    dragleaves = pyqtSignal()
    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(200,200, 400, 500)
        
        
        
        self.container = QWidget()
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout()

        self.container.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)
        
        for i in range(4):
            
            self.x = DragWidget(self, name = 'widget_'+str(i))
            
            self.layout.addWidget( self.x)
            
            self.x.setObjectName('widget_'+str(i))
            
            self.b = QPushButton('widget___'+str(i))
            
            
                                    
            
            self.layout_2 = QVBoxLayout()
            
            self.x.setLayout(self.layout_2)
            
            self.layout_2.addWidget(self.b)
            
            
            
            self.x.show()

    
        
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.whereDropped.connect(self.attdeta)
        
        self.dragleaves.connect(self.removeParent)
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def removeParent(self) :
        
        print("\n\nself.dragleaves.connect(self.removeParent))")
        pass
        
    
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)    
    def attdeta(self, tupx, tupy) :
        
        print("\n\nself.whereDropped.connect(self.attdeta)")
        print('tupxy : ', tupx , tupy)
    
    
    
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        pos = e.pos()
        widget = e.source()
        
        print('\n\ndropEvent _________')
        print('widget = e.source() :' , widget)
        
        print('e.pos()  : ' , pos ,'\n\n')

        
        self.whereDropped.emit(e.pos().x(), e.pos().y())

        e.accept()
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        print('dragEnterEvent _________' , e.source(), '\n')
        print('dragEnterEvent _________event-source-name :'  ,e.source().objectName())
        
        print('e.pos()  : ' , e.pos().x())
        
        print('e.pos()  : ' , e.pos().y() ,'\n\n')
        
        e.accept()
        
    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        
        print('\n\nDragLeaveEvent event : ', event)
        
        # print(event.sender())  ### AttributeError: 'QDragLeaveEvent' object has no attribute 'sender'
      
        # print(event.source()) ### AttributeError: 'QDragLeaveEvent' object has no attribute 'source'

        print("Drag left at: " + str(self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())))     
        
        
        print('self.dragleaves.emit()')
        self.whereDropped.emit(self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos()).x(), self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos()).y()) ## see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022465/how-do-i-get-the-exit-point-from-a-qdragleaveevent][1]
        
        self.dragleaves.emit()
        
        event.accept()


app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Any chance of getting sender/sorce/widget of `dragLeaveEvent` like for

`dragEnterEvent`  ??? :

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        print('dragEnterEvent _________' , e.source(), '\n')
        print('dragEnterEvent _________event-source-name :'  ,e.source().objectName())
        
        print('e.pos()  : ' , e.pos().x())
        
        print('e.pos()  : ' , e.pos().y() ,'\n\n')
        
        e.accept()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: what would be the purpose of knowing what you probably already know when the drag leaves? Or you thought you could get those data when another widget in an outside window gets dragged over?

Comment: is the question or the purpose unclear ? The question looks reasonable to me. The purpose is that I am experimenting with widgets and dragging and would like to remove/detach them from both parent and layout to create kinds of dockable windows that could be dragged out from my MainWindow application. Need to know which widget start a DragLeaveEvent to remove it from parent and layout

Comment: I see your point I could remove them when the DragEnterEvent start, but that could be when I rearrange the widget around in my Mainwindow (that won't be my case , but could revert to it in case there is no way to solve my answer)

Comment: No, I was under the impression that you wanted to know the widgets on which the drag is being moved *after* the event. Shortly put, you cannot get that information from the drag leave, but since you can only get that event after accepting a drag enter event, you can just get it there, and eventually is when the drag has left. Note that reparenting the source during a drag exec caused by it can lead to a crash, so if you want to achieve a behavior similar to QDockWidget/QToolBar, you should probably not use QDrag at all, but make the widget "floating" by setting the appropriate window flags.

Comment: any particular flag ??  or just parent/layout as in https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt-widgets-appearing-as-separate-windows/

Comment: or these flag : https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-window-flags/

Comment: In order to make a widget "floating" while keeping its Qt parent, you should at least set the `Window` flag. Qt uses the `Tool` flag when making dock widgets and tool bars floating. Then, within the "drag" operation, you could try to reparent it to the new window, but this is also problematic: reparenting a widget makes it hidden, and a mouse grabber widget loses the mouse control in that case. That's why most drag&drop UIs don't immediately "show" the new widget while it's being dragged: they normally just add a temporary placeholder where the cursor is, and eventually finalize it on drop.

Comment: Hi, thanks @musicamente , reparenting when cliking the widget close button was my initial idea, I'll try to learn QDockWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `QDragLeaveEvent` is always preceded by a `QDragEnterEvent`, you can store the source widget at the `dragEnterEvent()` and use it at the `dragLeaveEvent()`.

So, do like this.

```
...
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        self.drag_source = e.source()
        ...
        
    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print('dragLeaveEvent, drag_source:', self.drag_source)
        ...
...
```

Comment: mmhh , looks fine for one widget but applied to second one somehow it goes over first one that disappear even if already without parent... already garbage collected or reference rewritten , dont know what could possibly go out underneath pyqt5 and python stuff

Comment: can add them to a list, but dont know how to get them back to reintroduce in the Mainwindow

Comment: Could add a a new widget and new layout and insert my widget inside them calling last layout with a name associated with each widget and use that name to re-add my widget to that. As for the list , it should be shortened each time it gets to big using set if set(list) >= number of widget, not sure my widget wont disappear

Comment: @pippo1980 It's unclear. You can drag widgets only one at a time. Why do you need the source widget of an old drag event? Also I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you remove a widget? Then what is removed at what instant? You didn't provide a [mre] for that scenario. I think you should ask another question for that.

Comment: If I drag one at a time the first one just disappear when I drag the second using your answer.  I can prevent that with self.drag_source = list() and in self.dragLeaveEvent use self.drag_source[-1] as Widget to setParent(None).

Comment: @pippo1980 As I said, what about posting another question with a [mre] on that problem?

Comment: Yep I'll do. Do you think would be better to delete this one , or make another one ? I've been banned before for too many stupid questions , dont want to get there again

Comment: @pippo1980 This question is fine, although it would be better if you remove unrelated parts in your sample code. And for a new question, you need to clearly describe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So I am adding this code to complete the above answer, because only using:

```
...
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        self.drag_source = e.source()
        ...
        
    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print('dragLeaveEvent, drag_source:', self.drag_source)
        ...
```

Is not enough when I need to cope with more than one sub-Widget and need to be able to put it back on its original layout. I need to store some Widget info inside a dict. Actually I need to store the parent of the dragged Widget to be able to re-add it to both re-parent it to its original parent and add it to its original layout when I re-parent it. Like :

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        self.drag_source[e.source()] =  e.source().parent()
        
        e.accept()
```

Complete small code example, border and color make the exaple longer but needed to clarify the Window structure:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR
print("Qt: v", QT_VERSION_STR, "\tPyQt: v", PYQT_VERSION_STR)

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow,                            
                             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton)
                            
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QEvent, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap

class DragWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setWindowTitle(self.objectName())
        
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.drag_source = drag_source
        
        self.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEventNEW
        
    
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
                
        if type(source) == DragWidget :
            
            if event.type() == QEvent.Close:
                
                source.setParent(self.drag_source[source])
                
                name_wid = self.objectName()
                
                lay_inter = self.parent().parent().findChildren( QVBoxLayout , 'lay_'+name_wid.rsplit('_')[-1])
                            
                source.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEventNEW
                
                lay_inter[0].addWidget(self)
                
                self.drag_source.pop(source)
                
                event.ignore()
                
                return True
                
            else:
                return QObject.eventFilter(self, source, event)
            
        else:
            
            return False    
    
    def mouseMoveEventPASS(self):
        
        pass
         
    def mouseMoveEventNEW(self, e):

        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)

            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(600,200, 400, 500)
        
        self.container = QWidget()
        
        self.container.setObjectName('pippopippo')
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.layout.setObjectName('pippopippopippo')

        self.container.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)
        
        for i in range(4):
            
            self.layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
            
            self.layout2.setObjectName('lay_'+str(i))
            
            self.widg = QWidget()
            
            self.widg.setStyleSheet("""                                  
                                        background-color: yellow; 
                                        border: 5px dashed black;                         
                                """)
            
            self.widg.setLayout(self.layout2)
            
            self.widg.setObjectName('bigger_widg_'+str(i))
            
            self.layout.addWidget(self.widg)
            
            self.x = DragWidget(self, objectName = 'widget_'+str(i))
            
            self.layout2.addWidget( self.x)
            
            self.b = QPushButton(self.x.objectName())
            
            self.b.setStyleSheet("""
                                    QPushButton {
                                        background-color: red; 
                                        border: 5px solid black;
                                    }
                                    QPushButton:hover {
                                        color: yellow;
                                        background-color : green;
                                    }
                                """)
            
            self.layout_2 = QVBoxLayout()
            
            self.x.setLayout(self.layout_2)
            
            self.layout_2.addWidget(self.b)
            
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.drag_source = drag_source
        
    
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        
        e.accept()
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        
        self.drag_source[e.source()] =  e.source().parent()
        
        e.accept()
        
    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):       
        
        list(self.drag_source)[-1].setParent(None)
        
        list(self.drag_source)[-1].show()
        
        list(self.drag_source)[-1].setGeometry(50,50, 250,250)
        
        event.accept()
        
        list(self.drag_source)[-1].mouseMoveEvent = DragWidget.mouseMoveEventPASS
 
    def closeEvent(self, event):

        for window in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
              
            window.close()
           

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    drag_source = {}

    app = QApplication([])
    
    w = MainWindow()
    
    w.setObjectName('Name_Main-window')
    
    w.setWindowTitle(w.objectName())
    
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

I am not into `PyQt QDockWidget` (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDockWidget.html yet ; I'll have a look at them soon.

Here a pic, describing the output of my code:

[image]